# Vagrant Mount Command error

Tags: mac, mount, nfs, vagrant

I have a vagrant set up that was built by someone else at my company. Other co-workers say it works for them on their (similarly configured) apple laptops. When I run vagrant up, I get the following:

```
=> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222 
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges 

will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
mount -o vers=3 10.10.10.1:/Users/fe4c/aislegacy /vagrant
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Here's what I think is the relevant snippet from my VagrantFile:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
settings = YAML::load(File.read(configFile))
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
VagrantHelper.setBox(settings['provider'], config)
config.vm.hostname = settings["hostname"]
config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings["hostname-aliases"]
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"]
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8086
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :type => "nfs", :nfs_udp => false,   
:nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"], :nfs_version => "3" }, id: settings["mount-name"]
```

I've tried changing the nfs_version (tried version 1-6), that didn't fix it. If it's a problem with the NFS version, how do I determine what version to use? If it's a problem with the transport protocol, how do I determine which value to use.

Comment: I've also toggled the nfs_udp setting to no avail.